# Not all data come from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am sending object from `ASP.NET WebAPI`:

[image]

It is really strange, but there is no this object at client `Angular 4`:

[image]

I cannot understand where is the `MP_ShipmentLines` object? What can be a reason? How can I solve it?

I've assigned 'CarCount' at client side. There is no additional processing and this is the same object.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I've assigned CarCount at client side. There is no additional processing and this is the same object.

Comment: @downvoter why do you downvote? What's the reason! I am really interested for answer. Maybe I am doing silly mistake?

Comment: Does `MP_ShipmentLines` have a reference to anything from its parent object?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I am sorry what do you mean?

Comment: I'm looking to see if you may have a circular reference somewhere, that may be being dropped by the serialisation process. It's also worth double-checking the response in your browser's developer tools to make sure it's really not coming back from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you some debuging tricks, hope to solve your problem:

1- check address that you requesting to in browser url, *it must show you a json* you can check your json at [jsononlineditor.org](http://jsononlineditor.org), it will show you is your api works fine or not

2- print your *resived data* where you subscribe your request check this cause some problem like this is related to mapping json to your object

> Leave part of your code here to others can give you better answers, till now we only know you have problem and there is no idea why. and it wouldn't be angular or .NET problem.